# React-hook-form validation when input is empty. Conflict with Yup.matches

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I'm using React-hook-form and Yup to validation form. The field **firstname** I allow users to submit forms without filled this field, but if user fill this field, user can only fill string that matches my regex (my regex is check personal name). I am having the problem that when user submits the form without entering any value in the textfield, react-hook-form keeps validating and shows an error (this doesn't happen if I use Formik, but for performance reasons I have to use react-hook-form)

Link on codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-validationschema-forked-jrqn2k?file=/src/index.js:0-898

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

import "./styles.css";

const SignupSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().matches(/^[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/)
});

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(SignupSchema)
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input {...register("firstName")} />
        {errors.firstName && <p>{errors.firstName.message}</p>}
      </div>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I try `yup.string().nullable(true).matches(/^[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/)` but it's not work. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.when()` method. Please check updated schema below. tested and working fine in your codesandbox.

```
...
const SignupSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .ensure()
    // .matches(/^[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/),
    .when({
      is: (val) => val.length > 0,
      then: yup.string().matches(/^[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/),
    }),
});
...
```

Comment: I’m so grateful for your help. I tried removing the .ensure() and everything still works as I would like. So do I need to keep .ensure() or can I leave it out

Comment: `.ensure()` method is used to transform `undefined` or `null` values to empty string. you can check more details by reading here. https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringensure-schema. this is helpful if you are working with external data.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Solved the issue I was having as well.