# Yup How to get the value of field using .when on the same field?

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form, yup

How to get the value of field when using when on the same field ?

```
  email: yup
    .string()
    .when([], {
      is: (val: string) => {
        console.log('val = ', val)
        return true
      },
      then: (schema) => {
        console.log('schema = ', schema)
        return schema
      },
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to get the `value` of email in `when` condition at `is` location as well as at `then` location. then you have wrote everything correctly. just remove starting `[]` empty array in when condition. It you don't provide any `array` or `string` then value of current item will get at `is` location.

ref: [React-hook-form validation when input is empty. Conflict with Yup.matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326817/react-hook-form-validation-when-input-is-empty-conflict-with-yup-matches/)

I have updated the below as per your latest comment. I have tested this in my JavaScript file. so you might need to convert it as per TSX syntax.

```
email: yup
  .string()
  .when({
    is: (val) => {
      console.log('val = ', val)
      return true
    },
    then: yup.string()
      .test('testKey', 'error', (value) => console.log('value at then', value)),
  })
})
```

Comment: Nice that is what I was looking for. I'm now getting val in is but not in then ? I get schema but not a value of the field

Comment: I have updated code so that `emai`l value can get at `is` as well as `then` location